# package 'libhtml-parser-perl': Is a directory E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Tags: 12.04, perl

I encountered the problem few weeks ago. First I didn't pay to much attention and I let the server running, but for now, there is a lot of upgrades to be fixed and I'm stuck.

If I try to upgrade something the process will ended with the message below. Even the autoremove.

```
(Reading database ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: reading files list  for package 'libhtml-parser-perl': Is a directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

thanks

Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-48-generic x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo dpkg --force-all -P libhtml-parser-perl`

Comment: root@primus:~# sudo dpkg --force-all -P libhtml-parser-perl
dpkg: libhtml-parser-perl: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 libwww-perl depends on libhtml-parser-perl.
 spamassassin depends on libhtml-parser-perl (>= 3.43).
 libhtml-tree-perl depends on libhtml-parser-perl.
 libhttp-message-perl depends on libhtml-parser-perl.
 libhtml-form-perl depends on libhtml-parser-perl.
(Reading database ... 60%dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libhtml-parser-perl': Is a directory